# display inline document on partial page on ajax.action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax, file, content-type

I am calling an ajax.action link on a page. This will display the name of the document. While i click on the document, an ajax request is fired tot he controller, which will return a File Content Result and I want this file to be shown inline in the browser under the targetID div.

Code -                 bytestream = fs.ToArray();
                fs.Close();
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("inline; filename={0}", fileName));
                return File(bytestream, "application/pdf");

The problem is , the file is displayed as the stream and it is not displying the contents correctly.

```
    <legend>Document</legend>
    <% if (Model.PresentDocument != null)
       { %>
    <li><%: Ajax.ActionLink(Model.PresentDocument, "GetDocumentPage", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Document", action = "GetDocumentPage", id = Model.PresDocId }), new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "Document" })%></li>
    <%} %>
    <div id="Document">
    </div>
```

Do i need to do anything specific for this div to display the inline pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use AJAX to download files. One possible way to achieve this is to have a normal link and when this link is clicked use javascript to dynamically generate an iframe and point the iframe source to the controller action:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    Model.PresentDocument, 
    "GetDocumentPage", 
    "Document",
    new { id = Model.PresDocId }, 
    new { id = "displayPdf" }
) %>
```

which is you could AJAXify like this (using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('#displayPdf').click(function() {
        $('#Document').html(
            $('<iframe/>', {
                src: this.href,
                width: '300px',
                height: '150px'
            })
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

which assumes that your controller action is accessible through GET requests:

```
public ActionResult GetDocumentPage(string id)
{
    byte[] pdf = ...
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("inline; filename={0}", fileName));
    return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: Wow. this works like a charm. Thank you !. Is there a way the ajax 'targetID' can map to iframe? Basically in the code that i wrote, it downloads the stream properly to the browser but does not dispay the contents. Just wondering !

Comment: @Sanjay, no it's not possible. You need to use the `src` attribute of the `iframe` pointing it to a server script which will return the content.

Comment: Thanks ! In the controller code that you have written doesnt the return need to be FileContentResult?

Comment: @Sanjay, when you use the `return File` method, based on the type of the first argument you are passing it will return the proper content type.

Comment: yes, it works. You are the best! Wasted about a day figuring out why my file was not getting displayed ! . Thanks again